# Initial script for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to create an initial script for Elasticsearch?

For example, I prepare one JSON file with index 20 users and 20 books. 
I want to load it by the single request.

Example file:

```
PUT eyes
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "_doc" : {
            "properties" : {
                "name" : { "type" :  "text" },
                "color" : { "type" : "text" }
            }
        }
    }
}


PUT eyes/_doc/1
{
    "name": "XXX"
  "color" : "red"
}
PUT eyes/_doc/2
{
    "name": "XXXX"
  "color" : "blue"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bulk API for populating your index in one single call.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-bulk.html

```
PUT /eyes/_doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"name":"XXX","color":"red"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"name":"XXX","color":"blue"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"name":"XXX","color":"green"}
```